# empty 70-persistent-net.rules on SuSe 13.1 and ethernet device called eno1

Tags: networking, ethernet, opensuse, kde

openSuse 13.1 configured my network controller as eno1 during installation.

Also eno1 device can not be configured by KDE Network Connection tool, it doesn't allow you to add a connection for this device.

When i check the 70-persistent-net.rules it's blank. I would like to rename it as eth0 but also i couldn't.  I have to find a way to enable KDE Network Connection tool configuration because i will not use the machine.

Comment: What do you mean you couldn't?  What did you try?

Comment: @AndrewSchulman i think it's my fault it's written properly when i configured it via YaST ->NetworkDevices->NetworkSettings.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it via YaST2->Network Devices->Network Settings->overview tab :

you can rename the device.

Also if you want to enable KDE or Gnome network configuration applet, you need to enable

YaST2->Network Devices->Network Settings->Global Options: Control by applet.